# jquery tabs menu with images

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to create a tab control with images in it. Depending on whether the tab is active I would like to display another image for each of the tabs. It looks however that the current code only displays images meant for the second tab only?

I conjured up some code here: http://jsfiddle.net/5FVb7/

html

```
<ul>
                <li class="ico1"><a href="#tab-1">Title 1</a></li>
                <li class="ico2"><a href="#tab-2">Title 2</a></li>
                <li class="ico3"><a href="#tab-3">Title 3</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, the problem is because there are no div defining the tabs content linked from the tabs definition:

```
    <ul>
        <li class="ico1"><a href="#tab-1">Title 1</a></li>
        <li class="ico2"><a href="#tab-2">Title 2</a></li>     
    </ul>
```

For every href link there must be a div, documentation here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

I modified a bit your fiddle and the tabs change and image switch is working: http://jsfiddle.net/5FVb7/1/